# My Fedora Setup is gone due to accidental "yum upgrade"

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum

How to roll back? I tried `yum history undo 143` and `yum --skip-broken history undo 143` and get the following errors.

Important: All I care about is getting my kernel and custom graphics driver back to how it was -- the default kernel doesn't boot and my eyes hurt from the laptop monitor whose brightness can't be adjusted with the Fn keys at least.

The rest of the packages can stay or leave as they please it doesn't matter. So if any low-hanging fruit I can grab, it would be nice:

```
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: Package: nautilus-extensions-3.6.3-4.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: nautilus = 3.6.3-4.fc18
           Removing: nautilus-3.6.3-4.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               nautilus = 3.6.3-4.fc18
           Downgraded By: nautilus-3.6.3-3.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               nautilus = 3.6.3-3.fc18
Error: Package: 2:qemu-kvm-1.2.2-14.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.2-14.fc18
           Removing: 2:qemu-system-x86-1.2.2-14.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.2-14.fc18
           Downgraded By: 2:qemu-system-x86-1.2.0-23.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.0-23.fc18
Error: Package: 12:dhclient-4.2.5-15.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: dhcp-common = 12:4.2.5-15.fc18
           Removing: 12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-15.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               dhcp-common = 12:4.2.5-15.fc18
           Downgraded By: 12:dhcp-common-4.2.4-23.P2.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               dhcp-common = 12:4.2.4-23.P2.fc18
Error: Package: libreport-2.1.7-1.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libreport-python = 2.1.7-1.fc18
           Removing: libreport-python-2.1.7-1.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               libreport-python = 2.1.7-1.fc18
           Downgraded By: libreport-python-2.0.19-3.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               libreport-python = 2.0.19-3.fc18
Error: Package: openldap-2.4.35-4.fc18.1.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: nss-tools
           Removing: nss-tools-3.15.2-1.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               nss-tools = 3.15.2-1.fc18
           Downgraded By: nss-tools-3.14-7.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               nss-tools = 3.14-7.fc18
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
1:numpy-f2py-1.7.1-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy = ('1', '1.7.1', '1.fc18')
python-matplotlib-1.2.0-14.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
python-numexpr-2.0.1-2.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy >= ('0', '1.6', None)
python-pandas-0.10.0-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
python-tables-2.4.0-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy >= ('0', '1.4.1', None)
scipy-0.12.1-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
```

`yum --skip-broken history rollback 142` output is slightly different:

```
Skip-broken could not solve problems
Error: Package: nautilus-extensions-3.6.3-4.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: nautilus = 3.6.3-4.fc18
           Removing: nautilus-3.6.3-4.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               nautilus = 3.6.3-4.fc18
           Downgraded By: nautilus-3.6.3-3.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               nautilus = 3.6.3-3.fc18
Error: Package: 2:qemu-kvm-1.2.2-14.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.2-14.fc18
           Removing: 2:qemu-system-x86-1.2.2-14.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.2-14.fc18
           Downgraded By: 2:qemu-system-x86-1.2.0-23.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               qemu-system-x86 = 2:1.2.0-23.fc18
Error: Package: 12:dhclient-4.2.5-15.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: dhcp-common = 12:4.2.5-15.fc18
           Removing: 12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-15.fc18.x86_64 (@updates)
               dhcp-common = 12:4.2.5-15.fc18
           Downgraded By: 12:dhcp-common-4.2.4-23.P2.fc18.x86_64 (fedora)
               dhcp-common = 12:4.2.4-23.P2.fc18
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
1:numpy-f2py-1.7.1-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy = ('1', '1.7.1', '1.fc18')
python-matplotlib-1.2.0-14.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
python-numexpr-2.0.1-2.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy >= ('0', '1.6', None)
python-pandas-0.10.0-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
python-tables-2.4.0-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy >= ('0', '1.4.1', None)
scipy-0.12.1-1.fc18.x86_64 has missing requires of numpy
[root@y500-fedora
```

Comment: Have you tried `yum history rollback your_everything_good_transaction_ID`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thank you immensely for helping -- i am quite lost on this. I tried your suggestion to rollback to the previous transaction id but I still get errors. The errors are fewer though, so that's progress.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have edited the answer to add the errors from the command you suggested.

Comment: Keep going.  How about 'yum history rollback 141'?